# Search bar displaying results to another page

Tags: php, mysql, html, search-box

I have created the following search bar in order to display the product results. Although I managed to display them in the same page with the search bar, I cant create a redirection from the search bar to another page in order to display the results there.

The Search Bar:

```
    div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3">

    <form action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="post" class="navbar-form" role="search" >
    <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" name="searchcriteria">
        <div class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit" name="submit" id="search" value="search"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
        </div>
    </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

The rest of the code (for displaying the results):

```
if ($_POST['submit']) {

$searchcriteria = (trim($_POST['searchcriteria']) == "")?

die ("You did not enter any search criteria. Try Again!"):
mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, trim($_POST['searchcriteria']));

echo "You searched for : " . $searchcriteria;

$query = "select * from album_info where upper(title) like '%". strtoupper($searchcriteria) . "%' or upper(name) like '%" . strtoupper($searchcriteria) . "%'";

if (! ($result = mysqli_query($mysqli,$query)))
die ("There is something wrong in the query :" . $query . "</body></html>");
 echo '<table border="1">';

 while ($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $title = $rows['title'];
    $name = $rows['name'];
    $imagefile = $rows['imagefile'];
?> 
 <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
                  <div class="thumbnail">
                      <img src="<?php echo "img/".$imagefile ?>" />
                      <div class="caption">
                          <h3><?php echo $title ?></h3>
                          <p><?php echo $name ?></p>
                          <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Button</a> <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" role="button">Button</a></p>
                      </div>
                  </div>
             </div>
```

Comment: You've got your `<form>` action set to itself. Try putting a separate page there, and moving your PHP processing code to a different page.

Comment: What's stopping you from doing `<form action="results.php"...`? Then using your present PHP/SQL and putting it inside that page.

Comment: I've aldready placed the php processing code in a separate page. What I have to do now is to use action="Search.php"? Search.php is the page of the processing code.

Comment: Yep, that's pretty much it.

Comment: You can also leave all your code in one page but changing the action to Search.php, doing this will show your form on the next page, should they want to perform a new search without having to go back to the form; that's what I do sometimes.

Comment: Yes that is the case. I will try what you suggested!

Comment: It will work. @user3469716

Answer (score 0):

You can usee target="_blank" in order to open new page.

```
<form action="" target="_blank">
```

Also please use PHP-PDO or mysql_real_escape_string to prevention of SQL Injection attacks.